# Does LibGDX abstract OpenGL ES away or can I still use my OpenGL ES knowledge?

Tags: opengl, java, android, libgdx

I've been learning OpenGL ES, and am now turning my attention to using LibGDX.

My main concern with LibGDX is, if needed, will I be able to apply my OpenGL ES knowledge to something if needed and essentially override bits and pieces of the framework, or does LibGDX essentially hide any implementations of OpenGL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although libgdx largely abstracts away the OpenGL component for most of the basic things, you can still use it in your code for the more advanced stuff.

Usually though, if you dig a round for a while you'll probably find that about 99% of the time whatever you want to do with OpenGL has already been implemented somewhere in libgdx.

Source:

[Opengl-es-support](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Opengl-es-support)